# Update pie chart data at run time

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a pie chart implemented in d3js. I'm pretty stuck at how to update chart's data at run time.

```
jsfiddle link
```

This is the jsfiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/H2SKt/1/

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)?

Comment: Umm ... there was a reason that `jsfiddle` links required some additional code. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) should be exactly what you're looking for.